# Prevent EPiServer from wrapping content in <p> tags

Tags: wysiwyg, margin, paragraph, episerver

I'm working on a site in EPiServer, and whenever I create a page property with the type set to "XHTML string" (which uses the WYSIWYG content editor in Edit mode), it wraps all content in `<p>` tags.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I can't remove the paragraph margins universally through my CSS (e.g. `p {margin: 0 !important;}`) since I *do* need the margins for actual paragraphs of text. I've even tried going to the HTML source view in the editor and manually deleting the `<p>` tags that it generates, but it immediately adds them back in when I save!

It doesn't happen when the property type is either a long or short string, but that's not always an option since the content might contain images, dynamic controls, etc.

This is becoming a real nuisance since it's very hard to achieve the layout I need when basically every element on the page has extra margins applied to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that while I can't remove the `<p>` tags from the source view (because it adds them back in automatically), if I *replace* them with `<div>` tags, it'll leave things alone. It does mean that I've got an extra `<div>` wrapping some elements that I don't really need, but at least a `<div>` doesn't add margins like a `<p>` does, so...good enough!

Comment: You shouldn't mess up the semantics of your HTML code like this. Use CSS and a more detailed selector and "#idofacontainer p {margin:0;}" to remove margins of the P elements.

Answer (score 1):

As Johan is saying, they are there for a reason - [see more info here](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3878). That being said, it's not impossible to remove them. It can be done in one of two ways (taken from [world.episerver.com](http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=43969):

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    myEditor.InitOptions["force_p_newlines"] = "false";
}
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    force_p_newlines: false
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom TinyMCE-config that removes P-elements or strip them out using regular expressions either when saving the page or when rendering the property/page.

I think it's a bad idea though. P-elements are what the editors generate the most and in most cases their content is also semantically correct. Better to wrap your property in a div with a class and adjust margins using CSS like you mention.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of EPiServer with TinyMCE editors, you can insert `<br />` elements instead of `<p>` elements if you type shift-enter instead of enter. This should eliminate your margin problems.

More info at the link below:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_produce_P_elements_on_enter.2Freturn_instead_of_BR_elements.3F

EDIT: My comment below answers his question better.

Comment: That works for getting rid of the margins between multiple elements, but not if there's only one element in the content area. For example, if I insert just a single dynamic property, it still gets wrapped in a `<p>`.

Comment: Similar to what Tchami answered, there appears to be a TinyMCE init option to not force a root block.  I'm not sure if this will work for you, but its probably worth a try: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block

Comment: I don't have the ability to change the configuration myself, but I'll ask someone who does. That looks like that would do it. That's the exact problem - there's always a root-level `<p>` that I can't get rid of, even if I manually delete it from the source view.